# Most reliable Flash memory for an embedded Linux system?

Tags: memory, flash, linux

What would be the most reliable Flash memory hardware to use for an embedded Linux system?  I.e. one that has the least chance of losing data or getting corrupt when the power goes down?  The Flash would be for a Linux system so it would need to be at least 2GB in size.  Speed is not super important.  Cost is somewhat important, but not as important as reliability.  Candidate parts would be Compact Flash, raw NAND Flash, eMMC or some other type I'm not aware of.

We currently use micro SD cards but I don't like them, they seem too unreliable and I've had several either become corrupted or just completely die.  Another aspect I don't like is you don't get any visibility into what the card is doing at the lower levels, e.g. how many ECC errors are occurring, how many spare blocks are left etc.

We have a design re-fresh coming up so I wanted to see what the best hardware options would be.

Comment: Any speed or size limitations to narrow it down? Do a search for "rad hard flash". You might not need the radiation protection but some brands have power latch-up protection and other cool stuff.

Comment: It's for a Linux system so needs to be pretty big, e.g. at least 2GB.  No real speed requirements.

Comment: UBIFS on NAND ?

Comment: How well does UBIFS on NAND handle power failures?  And can you get any statistics on how much life is left in the Flash?

Comment: How about just using an embedded SD card? SD cards are very different, for example, some cheap SD cards contain a large die of mostly bad flash - the on-board micro does the testing to determine which blocks are good and what the capacity bin is: http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?p=3554 Presumably embedded SD cards are factory tested at true capacity and have published reliability statistics.

Comment: by embedded SD card do you mean eMMC (the soldered on variety)?

Comment: I was thinking more like these: http://www.cactus-tech.com/en/products/industrial-grade/sd-card/id-806-series. EMMC would probably work as well, but it has a different pinout, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tested some industrial SD cards and have two of them die completely.  They are just too unreliable.  Hence my search for a different technology.

Comment: This memory does not fail: http://www.maxwell.com/products/microelectronics/products/space-memories

Comment: The problem with your question is that it is based on a false premise: that the reliability is inherent in the device. It isn't -- the reliability comes from the proper design of the system in which the device is used. The system must either be able to recover from partial/aborted write and/or erase operations, or it must store enough energy to guarantee the completion of any operation it starts. As long as you meet the datasheet requirements for the device in question at all times, all of the technologies are about equally reliable.

Comment: Embedded Linux systems do not necessarily require 2GB flashes (anywhere near). It depends on what packages you select, and other considerations, like do you need unstripped binaries with debug symbols for all the packages.

Comment: I would like to suggest to potential answer authors to keep in mind the errors seem to occur on power-down file corruption. Perhaps a different file system or battery backup may be suggested. The parts I linked to are for space applications and are therefore at a minimum rad-hard.

Comment: A sample size of "some" industrial SD cards exhibited two failures.

Comment: From my experience a big part of the reliability is in the parts chosen.  I've had SD cards on one project completely die and two micro SD cards on the current project completely die, so wanted to avoid that format.  Those two uSD cards failed without subjecting them to a sudden power loss as well.  I wanted to see if using raw NANDFlash chips, eMMC or some other format had worked reliably for other people

Comment: I have edited some comments and removed some that discussed what should be on meta instead of the technical aspects of the question. Anyone who sees any continuation of meta-type discussion please flag it and it will be removed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to see what is done inside, you have already answered your question : you can't use managed flash, your only solution is raw NAND flash.

As you want reliability, you can't have 2 pages corrupted when a write fails, this excludes MLC and TLC flash. Go for 2GB SLC NAND flash (BeNAND doesn't fit your requirements). It's expensive, but it's your requirement.

But let's be a little more pragmatic, you need your system to boot and to avoid to be fully corrupted by a sudden power loss. This excludes SD cards, but it allows eMMC : eMMC were specified for embedded environments. Manufacturers like Micron and Toshiba offer eMMC that you can partially use as pseudo SLC to increase reliability for your boot partition, that use buffering to reduce data loss and prevent filesystem corruption, without handling all the ECC correction/page relocation/Bad block handling/wear-leveling stuff by yourself, and, with [JEDEC eMMC standard](http://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/results/jesd84-b50), you can learn about the number of available blocks, the mean/max age of your blocks, and you have dedicated commands to stop background operations, which allow you to perform a clean shutdown in about 20ms, instead of an indeterminate time with SD card. And this does not require a NAND controller with heavy ECC capabilities.

Comment: Thank you an excellent well informed answer.  I'll check out those eMMC parts further.